# Commuting diagrams with two cells in tikz or anything?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I am trying to typeset the following diagram, which is part of the definition of Kan extension, using xymatrix.  Here is a MWE of what I am currently trying to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all,2cell]{xy}
\UseTwocells
\newcommand{\lank}[2]{\mathsf{Lan}_{#1}({#2})}
\newcommand{\X}{\mathbb{X}}
\newcommand{\Y}{\mathbb{Y}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}
$$\xymatrix@R=30pt@C=30pt{
       \X \ar[rrr]^{F} \ar[ddrr]_{K}  &&& \Y \\
        &\rtwocell<\omit>{\eta} && \\
       && \Z \uurtwocell^{\lank{K}{F}~~~~~}_{G}{\alpha}& 
       }$$
\end{document}
```

Basically, the above is me trying to get xymatrix to produce a diagram with decent looking 2-cells.  I have also experimented with the following:

```
\xymatrix@R=30pt@C=30pt{
   \X \ar[rrr]^{F} \ar[ddrr]_{K}  &\ar@{}[d]|{~~~~~~~~\stackrel{\Downarrow}{\eta}}&& \Y \\
    & && \\
   && \Z \uurtwocell^{\lank{K}{F}~~~~~}_{G}{\alpha}& 
   }
```

Either of these conveys the message I want to get across, but there are some aesthetic qualities missing.  In the first, the two-cell arrows don't look very nice.  In the second, I could have spent more time getting the arrows to be the same size, and getting everything into the correct position.  This involves a lot of manual fiddling, which is fine if there is no other way.  My question is this: Is there any way to approach drawing such diagrams, with two-cells, in a uniform fashion.

Comment: This question appears very broad to me. Please read the documentation of `tikz-cd` or the part about `\usetikzlibrary{cd}` in the pgf manual. Everything not listed there will most probably be possible with pure Ti*k*Z. If you have some specific question about a two cell diagram, please add it to your post. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I am adding now.

Comment: Could you please make it so we can compile your code? I dare say TikZ can do this and I know a little TikZ. But I don't know what it should look like and I don't know what class or packages to use so I can't compile your code to see what you're talking about!

Comment: Without a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) it is impossible, for me at least, to tell what you are looking fro. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves everyone time:)

Comment: What is `\lank`, what is `\X\Y\Z`? Please help us help you and get rid of all this extra information. We can not compile your code an thus can't help.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

You can do this using [tikz-cd](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) with:

```
  \documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}
  \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
       X \arrow[r,"F"]  \arrow[d,"G"{name=G,left}]& Y \\
       Z \arrow[ur, "H"{name=H,right}, dashrightarrow]
       \arrow[Rightarrow,from=G,"\eta", to=H{shift left=1ex}]
    \end{tikzcd}
 \end{document}
```